# Read snort log via pipe or stream

Tags: stream, logging, pipe, snort

How can I read snort log via pipe or stream ?
something like this :

```
snort -l | myApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipes use standart input - "stdin", such as input from keyboard.
Then you can use same functions:

```
int x;

std::cin << x;
scanf("%d", &x);
```

And so on.

Comment: my problem is about snort. I could not get a pipe or stream from it

Comment: "-l <ld>    Log to directory <ld>" It's option for saving logs in directory.

Comment: I want to read snort logs directly instead of reading a file which has overhead.